# Wordpress log out according to url Parameter

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to log out the logged in user through the URL without going to log-in page or log out confirmation.Is it possible?

For example:

I am taking the URL `mysite.com/testpage?logout=1`. If the logout parameter is available in URL i need to log out the user without any log out confirmation and go to the `mysite.com/testpage` page is it possible?

please suggest any option for this

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for WordPress's [get_query_var()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_query_var). For example, you could define a function such as the following:

```
if ( get_query_var('logout') == '1' ) {
    // Log the user out
    // Codex: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_logout
}
```

Comment: get_query_var('logout') == '1'" this condition is not getting the parameter value :-(

Comment: What happens if you just `var_dump(get_query_var('logout'))`? You'll at least be able to see what's being captured...

Comment: I am getting  Output =>  String ' ' (length=0)

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `wp_logout_url()` function.

Example:

```
<a href=" <?php echo wp_logout_url(home_url('login')) ?> ">Logout</a>
```

Comment: Please read my requirement!!!

Comment: if you can analyze what I have given then you already have an answer to your "requirement".

Comment: this is clearly the answer you were looking for. the `echo wp_logout_url(home_url('login'));` will show the URL of logout and instantly redirect the user (in this case) on the home_url('login'); which means you can modify where to redirect the user.

Comment: I need to logout the user from URL request.Which URL the user coming<i need to redirect the user to same URL with LOG OUT.I it possible with this?. Can you please give that example?

Comment: Yes you can. Please look at the wordpress library and study about more of this. I just showed you the code you needed and instead of trying it, you still asking me if this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please use this following code :

```
if ( get_query_var('logout') == '1' ) 
{
    $redirect_url=home_url();
    wp_logout(); 
    wp_redirect($redirect_url);
}
```

Hope it will work for you.

Comment: I just tried with your code but I am getting "Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\xampp\htdocs\lwordpresssite\wp-content\themes\lwordpresssite\header.php:210) in C:\xampp\htdocs\lwordpresssite\wp-includes\pluggable.php on line 947"

Comment: Instead of "get_query_var('logout') == '1'" i used $_GET['logout']. At that time getting above ERROR. If i am using "get_query_var('logout') == '1'"No thing is happened

Comment: You can use isset($_GET['logout']) && $_GET['logout']==1 for it

Comment: But i am getting this ERROR at this time  C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpresssite\wp-content\themes\wordpresssite\header.php:210) in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpresssite\wp-includes\pluggable.php on line 947